# Google Maps Api draw my polygon (rectangle) as parallelogram

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I can't manage with drawing rectangle between two cities. I've searched everywhere on the Internet and can't find out why my polygon is drawn on Google Maps as parallelogram even so on 2d plane (not earth plane) this rectangle is drawn properly.

What I noticed is that the curvature sides of parallelogram depends on where cities are placed on map. If two cities are placed vis-a-vis then my function draw rectangle successfully. But If they are placed diagonally then my function draw parallelogram. The result should be rotated rectangle with height as distance between two cities and width as kilometers that user chooses.

Here is my function that should draw rectangle between two cities. As args we need to give position of first city ($x1 is lat, $y1 is lng), position of second city and as third arg a radius in kilometers ($l1) from center point of rectangle.

```
function getPolygon($x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$l1){
    var $l1 = $l1*0.010526; //approx kilometers

    var $distanceV = [($x2 - $x1), ($y2 - $y1)];
    var $vlen = Math.sqrt(Math.pow($distanceV[0], 2) + 
    Math.pow($distanceV[1],2));
    if($vlen == 0)
      return [[0,0],[0,0],[0,0],[0,0]];
    var $l2 = $vlen;
    var $normalized = [($distanceV[0] / $vlen), ($distanceV[1] / $vlen)];
    var $rotated = [(-1 * $normalized[1]), ($normalized[0])];
    var $p1 = [($x1 - $rotated[0] * $l1 / 2), ($y1 - $rotated[1] * $l1 / 2)];
    var $p2 = [($p1[0] + $rotated[0] * $l1), ($p1[1] + $rotated[1] * $l1)];
    var $p3 = [($p1[0] + $normalized[0] * $l2), ($p1[1] + $normalized[1] * $l2)];
    var $p4 = [($p3[0] + $rotated[0] * $l1), ($p3[1] + $rotated[1] * $l1)];

    var $points = [
    {lat: $p1[0], lng: $p1[1]},
    {lat: $p3[0], lng: $p3[1]},
    {lat: $p4[0], lng: $p4[1]},
    {lat: $p2[0], lng: $p2[1]},
    {lat: $p1[0], lng: $p1[1]}
    ];

   return $points;
}
```

Then I draw it on Google Maps like this:

```
new google.maps.Polygon({
  paths: getPolygon(first_city_lat, first_city_lng, second_city_lat, second_city_lng, 30),
  strokeColor: '#FF0000',
  strokeOpacity: 0.5,
  strokeWeight: 2,
  fillColor: '#FF0000',
  fillOpacity: 0.05
});
```

Here is an example should be rectangle between Birmingham and Oxford: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rxjp6vdq/)

[image: screenshot of issue]

Additionally I'm sure that kilometers converter is not exact and it again depends how cities are placed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earth is curved.  To get a polygon that appears rectangular on the curved sphere, you need to use calculations that take the projection of the map into account.

The Google Maps Javascript API v3 has a [spherical geometry library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry) that can be used to compute the desired points.

```
function getPolygon($x1,$y1,$x2,$y2,$l1){
  var points = [];
  var city1 = new google.maps.LatLng($x1, $y1);
  var city2 = new google.maps.LatLng($x2, $y2);
  var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(city1, city2);
  points.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(city1, $l1/2*1000, heading+90));
  points.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(city1, $l1/2*1000, heading-90));
  points.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(city2, $l1/2*1000, heading-90));
  points.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(city2, $l1/2*1000, heading+90));
  points.push(points[0]);
  return points;
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/rxjp6vdq/10/)

[image: screenshot of resulting map]

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", function() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_div"), {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(52.489471, -1.898575),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  });

  var trace = new google.maps.Polygon({
    paths: getPolygon(52.489471, -1.898575, 51.752022, -1.257677, 30),
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 2,
    fillColor: '#FF0000',
    fillOpacity: 0.05,
    map: map
  });

  var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
  for (var i = 0; i < trace.getPath().getLength(); i++) {
    bounds.extend(trace.getPath().getAt(i));
  }
  map.fitBounds(bounds);

  function getPolygon($x1, $y1, $x2, $y2, $l1) {
    var points = [];
    var city1 = new google.maps.LatLng($x1, $y1);
    var city2 = new google.maps.LatLng($x2, $y2);
    var heading = google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeHeading(city1, city2);
    points.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(city1, $l1 / 2 * 1000, heading + 90));
    points.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(city1, $l1 / 2 * 1000, heading - 90));
    points.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(city2, $l1 / 2 * 1000, heading - 90));
    points.push(google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeOffset(city2, $l1 / 2 * 1000, heading + 90));
    points.push(points[0]);
    return points;
  }
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

#map_div {
  height: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<div id="map_div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! That's exactly what I need. Thank you for sharing your knowledge here :)